# How to combine many to many join?

Tags: mysql, join

### Tables:

```
cust table:    
   cust_id, name, etc    

bill table:    
   bill_id, cust_id, amt, due_date, status (open/closed)

payment table:    
   payment_id, bill_id, amt etc
```

Customer can settle a single bill by paying multiple installments. So, one bill_id may relate to payment_ids.

### I am unable to generate this recordset:

---

cust_id | due amt

---

**'due amt' is the sum of all bill.amts - sum of all payment.amts and having status open.**

Bill table

```
bill_id cust_id     amt     status
1       18          200     open
2       18          200     open
3       17          200     open
4       17          200     open
5       17          200     open
6       17          200     closed
```

Payment table

```
payment_id  bill_id cust_id amt
1           1       18      50
2           2       18      40
3           3       17      10
```

Expected output

```
cust_id     due_amt         hint/how
17          590             (600-10) .. 600 -> because one is closed
18          310             (400-(50+40))
```

Comment: I think you don't have to exclude `b.status = 'open'` [br]What happen when a bill is completely paid by a single payment?[br] I believe that you sum the payment but exclude the bill amount from totals.

Comment: Yes looking into it now. Many thanks.

Comment: @JörjSvenssen I updated the question with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c.cust_id, sum(b.amt) - sum(p.amt) as due_amt
from cust c
left join bill b on b.cust_id = c.cust_id and b.status = 'open'
left join payment p on p.bill_id = b.bill_id
group by c.cust_id
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a3d9/3)

Comment: I tested your solution, but it misses out to sum "open" bills for which payments are yet to be received.

Comment: Can you please add example data and expected output to your question?

Comment: I added data and expected output. When ran in mysql, your solution was giving 190, 310 instead of 590 and 330.

Comment: Sorry made a typo: its 190, 310 and 590, 310. Because of join, it didn't take into account the bills which didn't have payments while summing.

Comment: I should have read this without bugging you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join